# Find the auto-complete Strings

Tags: java, html, rest

When you type a keyword word in the Amazon search box, you will get 10 auto-complete suggestions from a drop-down menu. I provide an illustration for that below,

[image]

How do I programmatically acquire them (the Strings) in the real-time using a RESTful GET call?

I program in Java and a `List<String>` will be the best format to have it.

Comment: List<String> is ok if the values you are going to get are just strings. If you need more data related to the string use custom object. If you have to retrieve the value from the DB use like match then return result into list then give it to API end. And I prefer the 3rd party libraries to perform the search or sort(like lucene or elastic)

Comment: The question is "how do I get those Strings"?

Comment: Just call the your endpoint using http get.

Comment: This comment doesn't help at all -  I know I need to call using HTTP, maybe I don't know which API to call and process?

Comment: Now I got the question edit it so that everyone can understand https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSECommerceService/latest/DG/ItemSearch.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think I find what I was looking for. Amazon offers -next to their affiliate API- a web service which can be used to get their autocomplete information. It can be utilized by calling an URL in the style of:

```
http://completion.amazon.com/search/complete?search-alias=aps&client=amazon-search-ui&mkt=1&q=samsung
```